# "IndentationError: expected an indented block" from a tutorial for Pygame

Tags: python

I followed a tutorial for Pygame just to get a feel for it. I am new to coding and instead of copying and pasting the code I typed them out myself. It worked fine in the video and I have no idea why a certain line is supposed to be indented when it wasn't in the video. I've gotten the error for line 51 and 54.

```
def show_go_screen(self):
  ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Tried to get the error code in correctly, this is my first time posting on here.

```
import pygame as pg
import random
import os
from settings import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize window
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.running = True

    def new(self):
        # Start New Game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()

    def run(self):
        # Game Loop
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def update(self):
        # Game Loop Update
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def events(self):
        # Game Loop Events
        for event in pg.event.quit():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False

    def draw(self):
        # Game Loop Draw
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)

        pg.display.flip()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        # game start screen

    def show_go_screen(self):
        # game over/continue
    
g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while g.running:
    g.new()
    g.run()
    g.show_go_screen()

pg.quit
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
def show_start_screen(self):
    # game start screen

def show_go_screen(self):
    # game over/continue
```

You can't just leave a function blank like in C or Java, you need to use `pass`.

```
def show_start_screen(self):
    # game start screen
    pass

def show_go_screen(self):
    # game over/continue
    pass
```

This should fix the indentation problem but I don't think the code will work as expected because the functions aren't there for no reason... Why would a blank function get called for no reason? You certainly missed something.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but now it opens then closes immediately, I missed the two "pass" from the tutorial.